# Verification of Proof that given x<0 and F'(x)=1if x$\geq$0 and F'(x)=0 if x<0 there exists no differentiable function F:R->R

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

My instructor wants me to show that if such a function $F$ exists it would necessarily be

1. continuous,
2. constant on any $x< 0$ and not including $0$, and
3. of the form $F(x)=A+Bx$ for $x\in [0, \infty)$.

From these three points I am to derive a contradiction.  I am quite sure my proof is not right and would like help editing it:

Assume that such a function does exist then it would be

1. constant on $(-\infty, 0]$ since $F'(x)=0$ and also,
2. have the form $A+Bx$ since $x\geq 0$, $A=0$ and $B$ would be the derivative, $1$ as given.

Since both of the functions on both segments are polynomials

3. $F$ would be continuous if it is made from two polynomial functions
   Even though $F$ is continuous it is not differentiable by taking the limit as h tends to $0$ from the left and right side of $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ we can see that one limit is $0$ and the other is $1$.

Since the two sided limits disagree, which means that the two sided limit of different quotient does not exist there exists no differentiable function F.

Please let me know how this could be changed.  The idea seems easy but I'm not sure how to express it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f'(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lr}
1 & \text{if } x\geq 0\\
0 & \text{if } x<0
\end{array}\right.$

For a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be differentiable, it must be continuous on each point, $x\in \mathbb{R}$, of the domain. The function $f$ must be constant on $x<0$ since $f'(x) =0$. Also, $f$ must be linear and of the form $f(x)=x+c$ on $x\geq 0$ since $f'(x)=1$.

Suppose, for a contradiction, $f$ is differentiable. However, then we may take the limit, $\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0, x<0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=0$ and $\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0, x>0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=1$. Since the limits disagree at $x=0$, $f'(0)$ can not exist. But we assumed $f'(x)=1$, a contradiction. Therefore, $\nexists f$ defined as above.